# If a child is a double in form (childByAutoID:userID), how can you ensure that a userID can only write for himself?

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

So user A writes to user B. He can only write with his own (user A) userID. This is my JSON

```
"Users" : {
 "02PdiNpmW3MMyJt3qPuRyTpHLaw2": {
  "usersWhoLikeToOtherUsers" : {
    "-Mkr0y9mO6d41XthDN4O" : "KGFrxFuhNHhP8vb3rKcTYzejATG2". 
    ////this is child byAutoId: userID.
```

So in the above example the user with userID `KGFrxFuhNHhP8vb3rKcTYzejATG2` can only write his own userID to the other user with userID `02PdiNpmW3MMyJt3qPuRyTpHLaw2`. He can't for example write something like `Jherilfj2wiwiufj` there

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense

Comment: @Tadreik I have updated it to make it clearer. Is there still something specific that doesn't make sense?